# Calculate $\sum \limits_{i=0}^n i^2 \cdot 2^i$

Tags: summation

Could anyone please help me with this:

$\sum \limits_{i=0}^n i^2 \cdot 2^i$

Comment: $i^2\cdot 2^i = 4i(i-1)2^{i-2} + 2i\cdot2^{i-1}$

Comment: I'm sure this question has been asked before on this site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comments on @Robert Israel's answer:

For $x\neq 1$,\begin{align}
f(x)\stackrel{\rm{}def}{=}\sum_{k=0}^n k^2 x^k &= \sum_{k=1}^n k^2 x^k = x\sum_{k=0}^n k^2 x^{k-1} = x\sum_{k=0}^n k\frac{d}{dx} x^{k} \\
&= x\frac{d}{dx} \sum_{k=0}^n k x^{k} =x\frac{d}{dx} \sum_{k=1}^n k x^{k}=x\frac{d}{dx} \left(x\sum_{k=1}^n k x^{k-1}\right) \\
&= x\frac{d}{dx} \left(x\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{d}{dx}x^{k}\right) 
= x\frac{d}{dx} \left(x \frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=1}^n x^{k}\right) \\
&= x\frac{d}{dx} \left(x \frac{d}{dx}\frac{x(x^n-1)}{x-1}\right) \\
&= x\frac{d}{dx} \left(x \frac{nx^{n+1}-(n+1)x^n+1}{(x-1)^2}\right) \\
\end{align}
Computing the last derivative gives you a closed-form for $f(x)$; now, it only remains to evaluate $f(2)$. I find 
$$ f(2) = 2^{n+1}(n^2-2n+3) - 6$$

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot!

Answer (score 5):

Hint: It's better to be more general here: replace the $2$ by $x$.  You know about geometric series, I hope.  Then note
that $x \dfrac{d}{dx} x^i = i x^{i}$...

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no knowledge whatsoever regarding series, so could you please explain what you've just written in a bit more detail?

Comment: @liek17: I've posted an answer to try and explain the approach suggested by Robert Israel (it didn't fit in the character limit for the comments).

Answer (score 0):

Consider

$$f(a) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} e^{a k} = \frac{e^{a (n+1)}-1}{e^a-1}$$

$$f'(a) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k \, e^{a k} = \frac{(n+1) e^{a (n+1)}}{e^a-1} - \frac{e^a (e^{a (n+1)}-1)}{(e^a-1)^2}$$

$$f''(a) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k^2 \, e^{a k} = (n+1) \left [ \frac{(n+1) e^{a (n+1)}}{e^a-1} - \frac{e^a (e^{a (n+1)}-1)}{(e^a-1)^2} \right ] - \\
\frac{1}{1-e^{-a}} \left [ \frac{(n+1) e^{a (n+1)}}{e^a-1} - \frac{e^a (e^{a (n+1)}-1)}{(e^a-1)^2} \right ] - e^a (1-e^{-a})^{-2} \frac{e^{a (n+1)}-1}{e^a-1}$$

In the final expression, plug in $a=\log{2}$.  Note that $e^a-1=1$, etc.  The result I get is

$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 \, 2^i = (n^2-2 n+3) 2^{n+1} - 6$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $$S_n=\sum \limits_{i=0}^n i^2 \cdot 2^i=1^22+2^22^2+3^22^3+\cdots+(n-1)^22^{n-1}+n^22^n$$

$$\implies 2S_n=\sum \limits_{i=0}^n i^2 \cdot 2^{i+1}=1^22^2+2^22^3+3^22^4+\cdots+(n-1)^22^{n}+n^22^{n+1}$$

On subtraction, $$-S_n=2(1^2-0^2)+2^2(2^2-1^2)+2^3(3^2-2^2)+\cdots+2^n\{n^2-(n-1)^2\}-n^22^{n+1}$$

$$\implies S_n=n^22^{n+1}-\sum_{1\le r\le n }(2r-1)2^r=n^22^{n+1}-P_n$$ setting $\sum_{1\le r\le n }(2r-1)2^r=P_n$

As $$P_n=\sum_{1\le r\le n }(2r-1)2^r=1\cdot2^1+3\cdot2^2+5\cdot2^3+\cdots+(2n-3)2^{n-1}+(2n-1)2^n$$

$$2P_n=\sum_{1\le r\le n }(2r-1)2^{r+1}=1\cdot2^2+3\cdot2^3+5\cdot2^4+\cdots+(2n-3)2^{n}+(2n-1)2^{n+1}$$

On subtraction, $$-P_n=1\cdot2^1+2^2(3-1)+2^3(5-3)+\cdots+2^{n-1}\{(2n-1)-(2n-3)\}-(2n-1)2^{n+1}$$

$$\implies P_n=(2n-1)2^{n+1}-2-2\sum_{2\le r\le n-1}2^r=(2n-1)2^{n+1}-2-2\cdot\frac{4(2^{n-1}-1)}{2-1}=(2n-1)2^{n+1}-2-8(2^{n-1}-1)=2^{n+1}(2n-3)+6$$