# Sum of the Series

Tags: calculus

I need the sum of the series
  $$\sum_{i=1}^t {(t-i+1)^2 a^{2(t-i)} }$$
it doesn't looks like arithmetic or geometric series but mixture of these two.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of summing it from $i=1$ to $t$, sum it from $i=t$ to $1$.

$$=\sum_{i=1}^ti^2(a^2)^{i-1}=a^{-2}\sum_{i=1}^ti^2(a^2)^i$$

And as per [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/460470/calculate-sum-limits-i-0n-i2-cdot-2i), we know that

$$\sum_{i=1}^ti^2x^i={(x (1 + x) - x^{1 + t} ((1 + t)^2 - (-1 + 2 t + 2 t^2) x + t^2 x^2)\over(1 - x)^3}$$

Comment: Thanks for your help but when I use the above formula for specific case e.g, t=3, a=0.7. Series sum and formula described by you produce different results

Comment: @Ali are you sure you put in the numbers right?  Note $x=a^2$.  What do you get with those values?

Comment: Dear Sir if I replace $$ 1-x^3$$ by $$ (1-x)^3 $$ in the formula given by you, Then I get the answer equal to the sum of the series.

Comment: @ Simple Art, Yes I used $$x=a^2$$. Now I got the same answer for t=3 and a=0.7. Ans=5.1209

Comment: @Ali Ah, that is a typo on my part.  Sorry.

Comment: Well, glad to help and that it all worked out :D

Comment: Thanks a lot for this favor.

Comment: @Ali Glad to help!  :D